# different bash output for same input

Tags: bash

I encountered some unexpected behaviour of my `bash`. This is my in-/output:

```bash
nepumuk@pc:~$  type URL
URL is a function
URL () 
{ 
    echo -e "${_//%/\\x}"
}
nepumuk@pc:~$  URL %2f
URL
nepumuk@pc:~$  URL %2f
/
nepumuk@pc:~$  URL %2F
/
nepumuk@pc:~$  type URL
URL is a function
URL () 
{ 
    echo -e "${_//%/\\x}"
}
nepumuk@pc:~$   URL %2f
URL
nepumuk@pc:~$  URL %2f
/
nepumuk@pc:~$  URL %2f
/
nepumuk@pc:~$  URL %2f
/
nepumuk@pc:~$    URL %2f
/
nepumuk@pc:~$   URL %2f
/
```

The corresponding part in the bash function file is:

```bash
url() {
        : "${*//+/ }"
        echo -e "${_//%/\\x}"
}

export -f url

URL() {
        echo -e "${_//%/\\x}"
}

export -f URL
```

During testing I changed the content of `URL` to `echo -e "${@//%/\\x}"` to see wether something changes. Opening a new terminal (emulator?) window with the latter being used, I get

```bash
nepumuk@pc:~$  URL %2f
/usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
nepumuk@pc:~$  URL %2f
/
nepumuk@pc:~$  URL %2f
/
```

Although I could fully reproduce (and use the former for it gives the desired output), but I'd be happy having an explanation.

Comment: What's unexpected, and what did you expect?

Comment: And probably more importantly, what are you actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: `$_` is expanding to the argument of the *previous* command - so not the "same input"

Comment: on the other hand, `$1` would be the first argument to the function itself, and `"$@"` would be all of them. It should work ok with `echo -e "${@//%/\\x}"`, the output you show doesn't seem to match that expansion

Answer (score 3):

In `bash` the `$_` variable expands to the last argument of the previously run command ([among other things](/q/280453)).

> ```
> url() {
>    : "${*//+/ }"
>    echo -e "${_//%/\\x}"
> }
> ```

Makes some sort of sense as the expansion of `${*//+/ }` is first passed as one any only one argument to the `:` no-op command.

That's intended to replace `+`s with spaces in the positional parameters and concatenate the resulting strings with the first character of `$IFS` inbetween (the usual effect of `$*` when quoted).

Then the second command takes that resulting string, replaces the `%`s with `\x` in it and passes the result to `echo`.

In `bash`, when the `posix` and `xpg_echo` options are not both enabled, its `echo` builtin supports a `-e` option which can be used to expand some escape sequences, some of those are `\xHH` which expands to the byte  with value corresponding to the 0xHH hexadecimal number. So it will replace `%HH` with the corresponding byte value so in effect do URI %XX decoding.

If you remove the first `:` command though, `$_` in the second command will be whatever last argument was passed to the command run before that function was invoked.

Here it seems whoever wrote that function used that `$_` trick to avoid having to use a temporary variable. That however makes the code unnecessarily complicated and hard to read and understand.

```
uri_decode() {
  local IFS=' ' # make sure arguments are joined with spaces rather than
                # make some assumption on what $IFS may currently contain

  local tmp="$*" # positional parameters joined with spaces

  tmp=${tmp//+/ } # replace +s with spaces

  tmp=${tmp//[%]/\\x} # replace % with \\x. Using [%] instead of % for
                      # increased portability.

  printf '%b\n' "$tmp" # pass the result to printf for expanding of the \x
                       # sequences, avoiding echo whose behaviour depends on
                       # the environment, and would give incorrect results
                       # for strings like -Enee
}
```

And if you want a variant that doesn't do the + -> space translation, just remove the `tmp=${tmp//+/ }` part.